# Handsontable not loading with dynamically created column headers

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am  working with handsontable and a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/kc11/o4d6gr6n/2/ . I am trying to dynamically load the data and set the column header names. Obviously the data is not loading. When I run jshint I get:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'identifier' of undefined
```

how can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

One thing that jumps out is that in your dataDump function you have

```
console.log('data of ' + name, hot.getData());
```

but your table is called hot1, so it should be

```
console.log('data of ' + name, hot1.getData());
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup, you have a few errors but the most important one is your option `columns`. Read the documentation again but basically you're setting that to an array of strings which is not correct. You're supposed to give specific options here. If you remove this line, it all works like a charm, more or less. You have other issues with your dump data button but that's more obvious (you copy pasted var names instead of assigning to the correct ones).

Hope this helps!